# Why does printf with too few arguments work on Cygwin?

Tags: c, cygwin

```
int main()
int a = 1 , b=2 ,c=3 ,d=4 ;
a= ++b;
c= d++;
print f("a = %d , b = %d , c = %d, d= %d" , a , b ,c);
return 0;}
a=3 b=3 c=4 d=5
```

---

I don't know why works this code nomally in cygwin
because I dont write about D in printf

Comment: This is undefined behavior. The program can print any value or crash. Apart from the intentional bug, the code in your question contains syntax errors and cannot be compiled. The output differs from the format string. Please copy&paste the code to your question, don't retype it.

Comment: is this bug of Cygwin Compiler?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. Please [edit] your question, **copy&paste** your real code and the corresponding output. Also show the command you used to compile the program. Probably you can add options to enable warnings like `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Undefined behavior means that the standard doesn't define what should happen, so anything is OK. That the value printed happens to be the expected value of `d` does not mean it is actually read from the variable `d`. The compiler does not know that your format string `...d=%d` refers to a variable named `d`. You could as well write `...a=%d`or `...x=%d`.

Comment: Sorry This question is University professor's quiz  // Thank for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

You are relying on undefined behavior by calling `printf` with too few arguments. You should never do this as the program will likely crash, and if it does run, the results will be randomly based on the specific compiler/system.

What is happening here is that `printf` is popping more variables from the stack than it is supposed too and is grabbing something from the stack from `main`. This is almost always going to cause some sort of stack/memory corruption later on in your program. Of course your code is short and so this is not happening in this simple case.

Comment: Function arguments are not always stored on the stack. (For Cygwin this may be the case.) Depending on the platform they may also be stored in registers. In C, normally, the calling function is responsible for cleaning up the function arguments, so `printf` will most probably not pop anything from the stack but only read from wherever it would expect to find the argument. That means it will not corrupt the stack by simply reading a non-existing argument. But anyway this is undefined behavior and anything is allowed to happen including data corruption or a program crash.

Comment: Thank for your answer!   I am helped a lot

Comment: For what it's worth Cygwin uses the Windows native calling convention like any other Windows program. In the case of variadic functions I'm not sure exactly how this works odd the top of my head, but in normal functions the first 4 arguments will be on registers (for 64-bit) `rcx`, `rdx`, `r8` and `r9` with some variations depending on what the data types are.